# Use global class for temp data storage?

Tags: c#, persistence

I have an application that writes user provided data into a XML-file.
Now I want to avoid writing and reading a file to/from disc each time I change data or read data.

Is using a global class an option (as global variables are actually not advisable)? Or are there other/better approaches?

Comment: xml serialization/deserialization on demand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a singleton object and store data in the object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: Thanks. It looks like what I was after